# How do I use Serde to serialize a HashMap with structs as keys to JSON?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I want to serialize a `HashMap` with structs as keys:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.68
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
    struct Foo {
        x: u64,
    }

    #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
    struct Bar {
        x: HashMap<Foo, f64>,
    }

    let mut p = Bar { x: HashMap::new() };
    p.x.insert(Foo { x: 0 }, 0.0);
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&p).unwrap();
}
```

This code compiles, but when I run it I get an error:

```
Error("key must be a string", line: 0, column: 0)'
```

I changed the code:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Bar {
    x: HashMap<u64, f64>,
}

let mut p = Bar { x: HashMap::new() };
p.x.insert(0, 0.0);
let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&p).unwrap();
```

The key in the `HashMap` is now a `u64` instead of a string. Why does the first code give an error?

Comment: @YjyJeff are you aware that JSON explicitly requires string keys ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types,_syntax_and_example))? (Serde probab!y knows how to turn an `u64` into a string but not your struct...)

Comment: @kazemakase  I realized it. Therefore, I derive the Serialize trait for the Foo struct.

Comment: @Boiethios Thanks! I fixed my example code.

Comment: @dtolnay Actually, the Foo are enum in my code. The enum contains u64 and string. I expect the HashMap to store u64 or string as keys and f64 as values. For example: 
{"key": 0.5, "9": 0.6}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [JSONs specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4), JSON keys must be strings. `serde_json` uses `fmt::Display` [in here](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/9b64e0b17ca73e7fbecace37758ff19bc35dea05/src/value/ser.rs#L437), for **some** non-string keys, to allow serialization of wider range of `HashMap`s. That's why `HashMap<u64, f64>` works as well as `HashMap<String, f64>` would. However, not all types are covered ([Foo's case here](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/9b64e0b17ca73e7fbecace37758ff19bc35dea05/src/value/ser.rs#L591)).

That's why we need to provide our own `Serialize` implementation:

```
impl Display for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.x)
    }
}

impl Serialize for Bar {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut map = serializer.serialize_map(Some(self.x.len()))?;
        for (k, v) in &self.x {
            map.serialize_entry(&k.to_string(), &v)?;
        }
        map.end()
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=31d8a3ee345317c110eafba76257a51d))

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. He derived the serde implementations for his types, so that should be sufficient.

Comment: Limitation lies on JSON serializer side. It requires keys to be `String` (or to be more specific `Display`).
On the other side, what behaviour would it incorporate? Keys looking like stringified structs aren't best looking and can be misleading in this scenario.

Comment: This one is definitely useful, I was having trouble serializing a BTreeMap and making some minor changes it works like a charm!

Answer (score 21):

You can use `serde_as` from the [`serde_with` crate](https://crates.io/crates/serde_with) to encode the `HashMap` as a sequence of key-value pairs:

```
use serde_with::serde_as; // 1.5.1

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Bar {
    #[serde_as(as = "Vec<(_, _)>")]
    x: HashMap<Foo, f64>,
}
```

Which will serialize to (and deserialize from) this:

```
{
  "x":[
    [{"x": 0}, 0.0],
    [{"x": 1}, 0.0],
    [{"x": 2}, 0.0]
  ]
}
```

There is likely some overhead from converting the `HashMap` to `Vec`, but this can be very convenient.

Comment: Note (since I keep getting this wrong myself) that this silently fails if the `#[serde_as]` declaration appears *after* the `#[derive()]` declaration

Answer (score 5):

I've found the bulletproof solution

- Extra dependencies not required
- Compatible with `HashMap`, `BTreeMap` and other iterable types
- Works with `flexbuffers`

The following code converts a field (map) to the intermediate `Vec` representation:

```
pub mod vectorize {
    use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};
    use std::iter::FromIterator;

    pub fn serialize<'a, T, K, V, S>(target: T, ser: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
        T: IntoIterator<Item = (&'a K, &'a V)>,
        K: Serialize + 'a,
        V: Serialize + 'a,
    {
        let container: Vec<_> = target.into_iter().collect();
        serde::Serialize::serialize(&container, ser)
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, T, K, V, D>(des: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
        T: FromIterator<(K, V)>,
        K: Deserialize<'de>,
        V: Deserialize<'de>,
    {
        let container: Vec<_> = serde::Deserialize::deserialize(des)?;
        Ok(T::from_iter(container.into_iter()))
    }
}
```

To use it just add the module's name as an attribute:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyComplexType {
    #[serde(with = "vectorize")]
    map: HashMap<MyKey, String>,
}
```

The remained part if you want to check it locally:

```
use anyhow::Error;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
struct MyKey {
    one: String,
    two: u16,
    more: Vec<u8>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyComplexType {
    #[serde(with = "vectorize")]
    map: HashMap<MyKey, String>,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let key = MyKey {
        one: "1".into(),
        two: 2,
        more: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(key.clone(), "value".into());
    let instance = MyComplexType { map };
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&instance)?;
    println!("JSON: {}", serialized);
    let deserialized: MyComplexType = serde_json::from_str(&serialized)?;
    let expected_value = "value".to_string();
    assert_eq!(deserialized.map.get(&key), Some(&expected_value));
    Ok(())
}
```

And on the Rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf1773b6e501a0ea255ccdf8ce37e74d

Comment: And finally I've released the solution as the crate, because needed it many times: https://crates.io/crates/vectorize

Answer (score 1):

While all provided answers will fulfill the goal of serializing your `HashMap` to json they are ad hoc or hard to maintain.

One correct way to allow a specific data structure to be serialized with `serde` as keys in a map, is the same way `serde` handles integer keys in `HashMap`s (which works): They serialize the value to `String`. This has a few advantages; namely

1. Intermediate data-structure omitted,
2. no need to clone the entire `HashMap`,
3. easier maintained by applying OOP concepts, and
4. serialization usable in more complex structures such as `MultiMap`.

EDIT: The crate [serde_jdon_any_key](https://github.com/tzcnt/serde_json_any_key/) is the most time efficient manner to implement this. Thanks to @HighCommander4 for pointing out the crate.

Alternatively, a manual implementation can be used:

This can be done by manually implementing `Serialize` and `Deserialize` for your data-type.

I use composite ids for maps.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug)]
pub struct Proj {
    pub value: u64,
}
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug)]
pub struct Doc {
    pub proj: Proj,
    pub value: u32,
}
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug)]
pub struct Sec {
    pub doc: Doc,
    pub value: u32,
}
```

So now manually implementing `serde` serialization for them is kind of a hassle, so instead we delegate the implementation to the `FromStr` and `From<Self> for String` (`Into<String>` blanket) traits.

```rust
impl From<Doc> for String {
    fn from(val: Doc) -> Self {
        format!("{}{:08X}", val.proj, val.value)
    }
}
impl FromStr for Doc {
    type Err = String;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match parse_doc(s) {
            Ok((_, p)) => Ok(p),
            Err(e) => Err(e.to_string()),
        }
    }
}
```

In order to parse the `Doc` we make use of [`nom`](https://crates.io/crates/nom). The parse functionality below is explained in their examples.

```rust
fn is_hex_digit(c: char) -> bool {
    c.is_digit(16)
}

fn from_hex8(input: &str) -> Result<u32, std::num::ParseIntError> {
    u32::from_str_radix(input, 16)
}

fn parse_hex8(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, u32> {
    map_res(take_while_m_n(8, 8, is_hex_digit), from_hex8)(input)
}

fn parse_doc(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Doc> {
    let (input, proj) = parse_proj(input)?;
    let (input, value) = parse_hex8(input)?;
    Ok((input, Doc { value, proj }))
}
```

Now we need to hook up `self.to_string()` and `str::parse(&str)` to `serde` we can do this using a simple macro.

```rust
macro_rules! serde_str {
    ($type:ty) => {
        impl Serialize for $type {
            fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
            where
                S: serde::Serializer,
            {
                let s: String = self.clone().into();
                serializer.serialize_str(&s)
            }
        }

        impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for $type {
            fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
            where
                D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
            {
                paste! {deserializer.deserialize_string( [<$type Visitor>] {})}
            }
        }

        paste! {struct [<$type Visitor>] {}}

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for paste! {[<$type Visitor>]} {
            type Value = $type;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("\"")
            }

            fn visit_str<E>(self, v: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
            where
                E: serde::de::Error,
            {
                match str::parse(v) {
                    Ok(id) => Ok(id),
                    Err(_) => Err(serde::de::Error::custom("invalid format")),
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Here we are using [`paste`](https://crates.io/crates/paste) to interpolate the names. Beware that now the struct will always serialize as defined above. Never as a struct, always as a string.

It is important to implement `fn visit_str` instead of `fn visit_string` because `visit_string` defers to `visit_str`.

Finally, we have to call the macro for our custom `struct`s

```rust
serde_str!(Sec);
serde_str!(Doc);
serde_str!(Proj);
```

Now the specified types can be serialized to and from string with serde.

Comment: This solution has the notable downside that you have to come up with and implement your own way of encoding the key into a string. A more automatable (but admittedly less space-efficient) approach would be to encode the key as an escaped JSON string, the way this crate does: https://github.com/tzcnt/serde_json_any_key/

Comment: @HighCommander4 thanks for pointing out the crate. This is arguable the most time efficient way. :)